# DVD ripper for Windows

Tags: windows, software-rec, dvd, ripping

I am looking for a good DVD ripper software for Windows. Looking for something that will easily rip the raw bits DVD to hard drive without any loss of quality.

Looking for something that will easily copy the VOB files to a server location for use with the [Window Media Center DVD Library feature](http://channel8.msdn.com/Posts/Use-Vista-and-Media-Center-to-make-the-best-digital-DVD-library-EVER/).

Answer (score 10):

I would definitely recommend [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)!

- open source and free
- packed with features

Comment: "rip the raw bits" .. handbrake converts dvd's to .mkv or .mp4

Answer (score 7):

[dvdshrink](http://www.dvdshrink.org/) is a good, free backup option for your DVDs.

Answer (score 4):

Browse the Video_TS folder of your DVD and copy the .VOB file

[VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) should have no problem viewing the files

Comment: Many DVDs now uses protection technologies (region code, intentionally corrupted file system, etc.) to prevent a direct copy of the files. You must use some tool that can recognize and bypass these; otherwise Windows explorer is just going to give you errors.

Answer (score 4):

I was answering https://superuser.com/questions/12489/dvd-conversion-software, which then was closed as a duplicate, so I'll post my answer here:
I have had success using a combination of the following Windows programs:
• [DVD Decrypter](http://www.mrbass.org/dvdrip/) and [DVD Shrink](http://www.dvdshrink.org/what_en.php): to decrypt the copy protection and customize the conversion settings for audio/sound
• [Quick Media Converter (QMC)](http://www.cocoonsoftware.com/) allows you to convert any video format to any other video format.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

[AnyDVD](http://www.slysoft.com/en/anydvd.html) is able to rip a disc bit by bit.

```
"Discs which cannot be read by Windows can be copied using the AnyDVD ripper."
```

[AnyDVD HD](http://www.slysoft.com/en/anydvdhd.html) does the same, but for BluRay as well.

Comment: Do you know of a standalone open-source that requires no installation?

Answer (score 2):

Personal favorite for 'fire-and-forget' is [FairUse Wizard](http://fairusewizard.com/). Use it to back up all my DVDs to my NAS for convenient house-wide viewing.

Note this is specifically including transcoding to XVid or DivX ... for a raw rip you could use a much simpler tool. This tool does the more complex thing simply.

Answer (score 1):

I ripped a DVD with ImgBurn the other day.  It's probably not as robust as the other applications listed above, but it does include a lot of great burning features (I use it as a general CD/DVD burning program).

Answer (score 0):

[DVD Decrypter](http://www.dvddecrypter.org.uk/) is ace for ripping ISOs, and includes DeCSS if required.

Answer (score 0):

Decrypting with [RipIt4me](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/RipIt4Me) or [DVDFab HD Decrypter](http://www.dvdfab.com/free.htm) (remove protections that DVD Decrypter & DVD shrink doesn't)

(And if you need to encode [MeGUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/): Not the easiest one but easy enough & powerful)